# Different "LoadModule php5_module" instruction for apache's virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache2, virtualhost

I have apache2 and php5.2 installed as module in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/php/"
```

Also I have php5.3 in C:/php53 folder.

Is it possible to use different modules for different virtual hosts?

For now I have to change LoadModule and PHPIniDir instructions and restart apache.

Comment: Load all the modules you need, assign them to different handlers and set .php to be parsed by the handler associated with the PHP version you want in each vhost. You can't selectively load different modules, since one Apache process will serve requests for all your hosts.

Comment: Hey Dan, could you give us some example of this configuration you have suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can not load two versions of PHP into apache at the same time.
However it is possible to run two different version of PHP using mod_fcgid instead.

I don't have a Windows machine right now so I cant verify that this works.
Anyhow I found some instructions how to setup FastCGI and PHP on windows from here http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/apache-mod_fcgid-and-php-on-windows/

There is one exception if you want to run different version.
You should not add the FCGI stuff in the global section but to each VirtualHost section instead

It should look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site1
  ServerAdmin admin@site1
  DocumentRoot "c:/www/site1"

  <Directory "c:/www/site1/web">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All

    ## FastCGI stuff
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "c:/php52"
    FcgidWrapper "c:/php52/php-cgi.exe" .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then set FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC so the directory where php.ini is located and FcgidWrapper to the php-cgi.exe file for that PHP version.

You have to repeat this step for all VirtualHost you want to run PHP. But now you can customize the PHPRC path and executable for each host so it is possible to run different versions and have them use different configurations.

Comment: I've followed these instructions an issue comes up:
`FcgidInitialEnv` is not allowed in the `<Directory>`.

When I Google search for a solution, I find suggestions to move the `FcgidInitialEnv` directive out of the `<Directory>`. However, when I do that, I still get the old version of PHP running.

Thoughts?